# Allow jest to use real console.log only by specific library/portion of code

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

When working with `jest` and `@testing-library/react` we disable the `console.log` by mocking

```js
jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => { });
```

but that will cause the output of `screen.debug` to dissapear too, which I don't want,

I want a way to disable all the logging except for `screen.debug` function, is it possible?

---

So far I've tried making a small utility function

```js
function disableLog() {
  const consoleLogMock = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => { });
  return function enableLog() {
    consoleLogMock.mockRestore();
  }
}



test('dropdown is rendering all options', async () => {

  let enableLog = disableLog();
  const mockOnClick = jest.fn((option) => { });

  render(
    ...
  )

  let dropdownButton = screen.getByRole('button', {
    name: /sort/i
  });

  userEvent.click(dropdownButton)

  ...

  enableLog();
  screen.debug()
  enableLog = disableLog();
  
  ...

});
```

but it didn't work for me, the logging is still there

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the `screen.debug()` method:

```js
// pretty-dom.js
const logDOM = (...args) => {
  const userCodeFrame = getUserCodeFrame()
  if (userCodeFrame) {
    console.log(`${prettyDOM(...args)}\n\n${userCodeFrame}`)
  } else {
    console.log(prettyDOM(...args))
  }
}

// screen.js
const debug = (
  element?: Array<Element | HTMLDocument> | Element | HTMLDocument,
  maxLength?: number,
  options?: OptionsReceived,
): void =>
  Array.isArray(element)
    ? element.forEach(el => logDOM(el, maxLength, options))
    : logDOM(element, maxLength, options)
```

As you can see, `console.log` is used by the `logDOM` function. So, there are three ways to solve your issue:

**Option 1**. Use `console.debug()` or `console.info()` API instead.

**Option 2**. Create your own logger tool and mock its methods rather than the `console.log()` method. So that it will not break its original implementation.

```
// logger.js
const logger = {
  log: (...args) => console.log(...args),
};

jest.spyOn(logger, 'log').mockImplementation(() => {});
```

**Option 3**. Your solution should work. Use `spy.mockRestore()` to restore the mock to its original implementation before using `screen.debug()` method.

E.g.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";

function disableLog() {
  const consoleLogMock = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => { });
  return function enableLog() {
    consoleLogMock.mockRestore();
  }
}

describe('74726842', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const enableLog = disableLog()
    const TestComp = () => {
      console.log('test comp render');
      return <div>test</div>
    }
    render(<TestComp />);
    enableLog();
    screen.debug();
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74726842/index.test.tsx
  74726842
    ✓ should pass (32 ms)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          test
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    
    /workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/stackoverflow/74726842/index.test.tsx:20:12
      18 |     render(<TestComp />);
      19 |     enableLog();
    > 20 |     screen.debug();
         |            ^

      at logDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:80:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.591 s, estimated 12 s
```